# error when i try to exit the program in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

> I tried quit(0) and sys.exit too

```
import random 

word = random.choice(open(r"C:\Users\Sigma.jota3\Documents\new.txt").read().split()).strip()
word = list(word)
print ' '.join(word)

word_2 = []

for i in range(len(word)):
    word_2.append("_")

print ' '.join(word_2)


word_3 = [] 


count = 0 


numbers_to_count = len(word)


while True:    

    word_input = raw_input("")     

    word = ''.join(word) 

    for el in range(len(word)):
        if not word[el] != word_input:
            word_3.append(word[el])
            numbers_to_count = numbers_to_count - 1 
            print "your answer is right!, now you have %s letters to resolve!" % numbers_to_count
        if numbers_to_count == 0:
            print "Congratulations, you win!"
            exit(0) 
        if numbers_to_count < 0:
            exit(0) 

    for le in range(len(word)):
        word_word_input = word.find(word_input)  
        if word_word_input < 0: 
            count = count + 1
            print "Try again, you have failed in %s times!" % count
        if count > 7:
            print "Tip: The word have %s letters." % len(word)  
        if count > 12:
            print "You lose!, you made more than %s tries." % count
            exit(0)
```

Comment: What is the error ? Please edit the question and mention the stack-trace

Comment: ``exit`` is not a global function; it's defined in the ``sys`` module.  So, you'd need ``import sys`` at the top of the script, and ``sys.exit(0)`` to actually exit.  Or alternatively, ``from sys import exit`` at the top, and leave the ``exit(0)``s alone.

Comment: oh, thanks jason, i will see it now

Comment: im still having troubles with the code

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `import sys` in your code. If you do have the import in your code, then [sys.exit() how to use it python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639077/sys-exit-how-to-use-it-python) I also see in your code that you use `exit(0)`. That will only work if you have `from sys import exit` However since you say that you tried `sys.exit(0)`, then you probably need to have the import statement added.

`sys.exit()` raises a `SystemExit` exception. This may be what you are seeing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line xx, in <module>
sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

Comment: i used the import sys in this code when i used sys.exit(0)

Comment: What troubles are you having?

Comment: well, in the cmd, the code exit - 
but in the console of python, not

Comment: @GuilhermeRafael I do not understand what you mean

Comment: the code really quits and exits of python console when the game is over in the cmd

Comment: but in the python console, when i put the code to run, the code dont quit  and exit

Comment: @GuilhermeRafael what does it do?