# How Can I Make a Python Script to Get a Return?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, keep-alive

I want to make a script with python for bash that returns 1 or 0, how can I do that? To make more clear I can give that example:

I am trying to do configurations for keepalived and it needs a script that returns 0 or 1 to check whether an application is running or not, but I have no idea how to make that script with python?

There is an example code but it uses .sh instead of .py, I want to make this with .py script:

```
vrrp_script chk_myscript {
script       "/usr/local/bin/mycheckscript.sh" # the script must be .py
interval 2   # check every 2 seconds
fall 2       # require 2 failures for KO
rise 2       # require 2 successes for OK
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sys.exit should do the trick

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

and

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

[How to use sys.exit() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639077/how-to-use-sys-exit-in-python)

Comment: so we must use "sys.exit(1)" instead of "return 1" in our .py script, am I right?

Comment: return 1, returns value from function. sys.exit stops program and returns value from program,

Comment: The script in the code I gave returns 0 or 1 (this mycheckscript.sh), how would I return that, should I return before sys.exit?

Comment: it should be mycheckscript.py and you need to put sys.exit in it. no you should use sys.exit to return from script.

Comment: I make what you say but I think the sys.exit is not accepted as a return. The program says this: /usr/local/bin/mycheckscript.py exited with status 2.
Do you know what doest it mean?